# Pentaho - repository Creation Issue

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-cde, pentaho-design-studio, pentaho-ctools

Am trying to create Repository in Pentaho DI by using SQl server and Mysql, in that am facing a issue,

Please some one can help me to resolve that .

```
Repositary login failed.
Detailed cause:org.pentaho.di.core.exception,kettleException:
Error connecting to the repositary!The version of the repository is -1.-1.
    This Kettle edition requires it to be at least version 5.0 and as such an upgrade is required.

    To upgrade, backup your database and export the repository to XML for additional safety.

    Then select the 'Edit' button followed by the 'Create or Upgrade' button.

    Please consult the Upgrade Guide for eventually special instructions for this version.
```

Comment: What happens when you follow the instructions? Also, I was not able to create a repo on SQL Server because its SQL dialect is no standard compliant enough. I recommend putting the repo on MySQL.

Comment: @Brian.D.Myers, I created Repo on Mysql successfully,but in SQl server it makes trouble. During the creation of Rep I didn't give any password,While updating it throws an error (Invalid Credentials). I tried the default username/password : admin/admin.

Comment: Can you make a simple transform and use a `Table Input` step to just select some data? I'm wondering if you can connect to any SQL Server DB at all. I suspect you're needing to copy the sqljdbc_auth.dll file to a place where the driver can find it. In my install, I added it to the LIBSPATH variable in spoon.bat.

Comment: @Brian.D.Myers i did lot of transformations and jobs and did so many things in SQL Server and i used for the past one more years ,Now am troubling only for connecting Repos for SQL server :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following steps:

1. Check the existence of
   "\data-integration\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.16-bin.jar
2. create a new database as repository,
3. select button [create|update], when select Dry run, please select N.

See dialog screenshot

[image]